# OSGi local integration test failing on lean example project

Tags: java, junit, osgi, declarative-services, pax-exam

I've set up a maven, osgi, pax, declarative service test project and I'm experiencing strange behaviour. There is a problem with the integration test which uses a declarative service.

The tests aborts with a error (the log is below) when ran locally via `mvn install`. When I execute it as a junit test case via eclipse it works. It also works when the same exact maven command is called on the ci server (logs are also below).

So obviously I'm missing something here. Could you please help me out and explain what is going wrong?

---

**DATA**

error logs    :https://github.com/mbe24/mode/issues/2
ci build log  :https://travis-ci.org/mbe24/mode/builds/36392361

```
$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.2.2 (45f7c06d68e745d05611f7fd14efb6594181933e; 2014-06-17T15:51:42+02:00)
Maven home: C:\DEV\maven\apache-maven-3.2.2
Java version: 1.8.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "dos"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with [pax exam and its dependencies](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-3813) and java 8.
But the developers are [currently working on it](https://ops4j1.jira.com/browse/PAXEXAM-619).

Changing to java 7 fixed all my issues, except the one with infinitests. It still kept failing,
because I apparently exported different versions of the same package.

The project is kept pretty lean, if you want to take a look at it.